# How to find critical resistance in parallel damped circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

As the topic suggest, how to find this value? After some research i found a formula but for series crciuts .

$$R=2\sqrt{\frac {L}{C}}$$

Comment: For critical damping, assuming R, L, C in parallel, \$\zeta=1\$ is obtained when \$R=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$

Comment: Now ---- use that value for dampening your VDD LCR networks, to prevent VDD ringing. With 100uF and 10nH, you need 0.5 * sqrt(1e-8/1e-4) = 0.5 * sqrt(1e-4) = 0.5 * 10milliOhms. That value, 5milliOhms, is 10 squares of PCB copper for standard 1 ounce/foot^2 foil and thus is FREE if you design the VDD network and the GND paths.

Answer (score 2):

The Q factor is important for what you want: -

[image]

Wiki information taken from [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor).

For critical damping Q = 0.5 (\$\zeta\$ = 1): -

[image]

Because \$Q=\dfrac{1}{2\zeta}\$

Answer (score 1):

If only I had the fast analytical circuits techniques (FACTs) to determine the quality factor of these series or parallel networks while I was sweating in university :-) Look at the below sketches to determine the denominator \$D(s)\$ of this parallel impedance in a few steps. To determine an impedance - which is a transfer function - you excite (the *stimulus*) with a current source while the *response* is the voltage across the current source terminals. For the denominator, we want the natural time constants \$\tau\$. We reduce the excitation to 0 (remove the current source when set to 0 A) and "look" at the resistances driving each of the energy-storing elements. Here, because we have two of these with independent state variables, this is a second-order network. As shown in the below sketch, determine \$\tau_1\$ and \$\tau_2\$:

\$\tau_1=0\$ and \$\tau_2=\frac{L_2}{R}\$

From these, we can form \$b_1=\tau_1+\tau_2=\frac{L_2}{R}\$

[image]

Then, for the second-order term, we set \$L_2\$ in its hi-frequency state (replace it by an open-circuit) and look at the resistance offered by \$C_1\$ terminals. We have \$R\$, therefore:

\$b_2=\tau_2\tau_{21}=\frac{L_2}{R}RC_1=L_2C_1\$

We can now form the denominator \$D(s)\$

\$D(s)=1+sb_1+s^2b_2=1+s\frac{L_2}{R}+s^2L_2C_1\$

By identification with a 2nd-order canonical form, we can define the quality factor \$Q\$ by \$Q=\frac{\sqrt{b_2}}{b_1}=R\sqrt{\frac{C_1}{L_2}}\$

Now, if you want to be critically damped, it means the quality factor is 0.5, implying that both roots of \$D\$, the poles, are coincident. The response for \$Q=0.5\$ as nicely documented by Andy Aka is non-ringing because the roots are real for this value. As soon as \$Q\$ exceeds 0.5, the roots split and become complex conjugate: overshoot occurs. To determine the resistance value to get \$Q=0.5\$, you solve \$R\sqrt{\frac{C_1}{L_2}}=0.5\$ which leads to \$R=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{L_2}{C_1}}\$

As you can see, I did not write a single equation and did just draw small sketches that I *inspected*. This is the power of FACTs that I invite you to discover at a seminar taught at APEC in 2016:

http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf

You can also look at the examples described step by step in the dedicated book:

http://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/List%20of%20FACTs%20examples.pdf

FACTs look a bit mysterious at first sight but they are not because they rely on physical variables of all networks - passive or active - their time constants. By starting slowly with simple examples you will enjoy determining complicated transfer functions in your head, without writing a single line of algebra. A lot of these techniques are based on the Extra-Element Theorem forged by Dr. Middlebrook: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of when to use [electrical duals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(electrical_circuits)).

Since you know the formula for the resistance required for critical damping of a series RLC circuit, take the dual of the formula to find the *conductance* required for critical damping of a *parallel* GCL circuit:

$$R_{crit} = 2\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad G_{crit}=2\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}$$

Since conductance is the reciprocal of resistance, the parallel resistance for critical damping is then

$$R_{crit} = \frac{1}{G_{crit}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}} $$